# Deploy from bitbucket pipelines to server through SSH with ProxyCommand and Gateway

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a deployment process perfectly working with my computer which i'd like to use in bitbucket pipelines.

The SSH Config file defines the connection :

```
Host my-host
    User my-user
    Hostname my-host-name
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ProxyCommand ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -W %h:%p my-user@my-gateway.com
```

My `id_rsa.pub` is in both `.ssh/authorized_keys` files.

The SSH connection works like a charm.

I generate a SSH Key pair for bitbucket pipelines and putted it in those same `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Here is my pipeline to test the ssh connection :

```
image: node:8.11.2    
pipelines:
  branches:
    stage/development:
      - step:
          caches:
            - node
          script:
          - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          - (umask  077 ; echo $DEV_PIPELINE_KEY | base64 --decode > ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
          - cat bitbucket-ssh-config >> ~/.ssh/config
          - ssh my-host
```

The `$DEV_PIPELINE_KEY` represents my private key stored in bitbucket.
The `bitbucket-ssh-config` file is the same as the above one.

It succeed in the gateway ssh connection but then it fails and I don't get why.
Here are the logs :

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
>
> OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to GATEWAY_HOST.com [GATEWAY_IP] port
>   22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa type
>   -1
>
> debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
>
> debug1: identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa-cert
>   type -1
>
> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4
>
> debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version
>   OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat
>   0x04000000
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>
> debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>
> debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>
> debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>
> debug1: Server host key: RSA
>   GATEWAY_FINGERPRINT
>
> debug1: Host 'GATEWAY_HOST.com' is known and matches the RSA
>   host key.
>
> debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
>
> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   'GATEWAY_IP' to the list of known hosts.
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>
> debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
>
> Authenticated to GATEWAY_HOST.com ([GATEWAY_IP]:22).
>
> debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd my-host:22
>
> debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
>
> debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
>
> debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
>
> debug1: Entering interactive session.
>
> debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com
>   want_reply 0
>
> ```
>       Host key verification failed.
> ```
>
> debug1: channel 0: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 0 for my-host
>   port 22, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 65536,
>   nchannels 1
>
> debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
>
> debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
>
> debug1: Killed by signal 1.